# ¿Cómo seleccionar el contenido de un código html a través de JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Tengo el siguiente código HTML:

```
<div class="btc_form btc6" id="btc_form">Please send <b>0.00250000 BTC</b> to <i><a href="bitcoin:1LQHRouoU3DicTnJ5ZJ8nSfFxUGWPBnmcg?amount=0.00250000&amp;message=Deposit+to+Coin+Builder+LTD+User+prueba1">1LQHRouoU3DicTnJ5ZJ8nSfFxUGWPBnmcg</a></i><br></div>
```

¿Cómo haría para obtener el contenido que está dentro de las etiquetas  "a" mediante **js/jquery** y tenerlo en una variable?

```
<a href="bitcoin:1LQHRouoU3DicTnJ5ZJ8nSfFxUGWPBnmcg?amount=0.00250000&amp;message=Deposit+to+Coin+Builder+LTD+User+prueba1">1LQHRouoU3DicTnJ5ZJ8nSfFxUGWPBnmcg</a>
```

En este caso obtener nada más  **1LQHRouoU3DicTnJ5ZJ8nSfFxUGWPBnmcg**

Comment: Falta indicar que es lo que has buscado/investigado. Referencia [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza `.text()`. Te permite obtener el texto de un elemento html:

```js
var datos = $("#btc_form a").text();

console.log(datos);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btc_form btc6" id="btc_form">Please send <b>0.00250000 BTC</b> to <i><a href="bitcoin:1LQHRouoU3DicTnJ5ZJ8nSfFxUGWPBnmcg?amount=0.00250000&amp;message=Deposit+to+Coin+Builder+LTD+User+prueba1">1LQHRouoU3DicTnJ5ZJ8nSfFxUGWPBnmcg</a></i><br></div>
```

Comment: Gracias amigo esta misma es! se me habia olvidado  esa novedad del jquery

Answer (score 2):

Hay varias formas para hacerlo, acá te presento 2 para **JS**

Con `textContent` y `querySelector` de la siguiente forma:

```js
var contenido_a = document.querySelector("#btc_form a").textContent;
console.log(contenido_a);
```

```html
<div class="btc_form btc6" id="btc_form">Please send <b>0.00250000 BTC</b> to <i><a href="bitcoin:1LQHRouoU3DicTnJ5ZJ8nSfFxUGWPBnmcg?amount=0.00250000&amp;message=Deposit+to+Coin+Builder+LTD+User+prueba1">1LQHRouoU3DicTnJ5ZJ8nSfFxUGWPBnmcg</a></i><br></div>
```

O también con `getElementsByTagName`, así:

```js
 var contenido_a = document.getElementById("btc_form").getElementsByTagName("a")[0].textContent;
 console.log(contenido_a);
```

```html
<div class="btc_form btc6" id="btc_form">Please send <b>0.00250000 BTC</b> to <i><a href="bitcoin:1LQHRouoU3DicTnJ5ZJ8nSfFxUGWPBnmcg?amount=0.00250000&amp;message=Deposit+to+Coin+Builder+LTD+User+prueba1">1LQHRouoU3DicTnJ5ZJ8nSfFxUGWPBnmcg</a></i><br></div>
```

De cualquier forma te dejo un poco de documentación:

- [textContent](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_textcontent.asp)
- [querySelector](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp)